# Is there a concurrency with UPDATE count=count+1?

Tags: sql, database, concurrency

I wanted to know, will I run into any concurrency problem with this?

This is NOT in a transaction. This code is for `Sqlite(prototype)`, but I plan to use it with either MySql or a SQL from MS

```
                command.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE tag_name SET count = count+1 "+
                    "WHERE tagid=@tagid";
                command.Parameters.Add("@tagid", DbType.Int64).Value = tagId;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Just be careful you don't reference count in the WHERE clause. Otherwise you may end up with a "Halloween Problem" of your own (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the halloween problem. I have no doubt that if you did not mention it i would have ran into that problem and wonder/complain about the problem all day (or week!) +1000 if i could :)

Comment: I hope none of my bugs end up in wikipedia!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this shouldn't be a problem. By default the locking mechanism should take care of any concurrency issues in single statements.

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you would have a problem; the tag_name table I would think would be locked while the UPDATE occurs, so that any other updates waiting to be executed would essentially be queued up rather than occurring concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, I vaugely remember seeing something like this in a SQL server best practices example from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

**not a problem** You will have implicit transaction anyway. So it should not be a problem.

Even if you change TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL, it should work just fine, at least on SQLServer.